# TinyMCE Premium Plugin Errors

Tags: tinymce

I just started getting a ton of errors today on my website using TinyMCE.  21 total alerts popping up on this one page, 3 times which has 3 tinymce forms on it.

[image: 1]

Any help with removing the alerts would be greatly appreciated.

looked through the javascript and plugins list, but don't see how to remove these premium plugins.

Answer (score 0):

All of the plugins listed in your screenshot are commercial plugins that require a paid subscription to use via tiny.cloud.

If you do not have a paid plan you will need to remove these specific plugins from the `plugins` option in your TinyMCE configuration.  The configuration should look something like this:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
        "advlist", "anchor", "autolink", "charmap", "code", 
        "help", "image", "insertdatetime", "link", "lists", "media", 
        "preview", "searchreplace", "table", "visualblocks", 
    ],
    ...
});
```

...just make sure the `plugins` option does not include any of these commercial plugins and the errors will no longer show.